# How to count all data based on the given date range except the existing see the table below

Tags: sql

> Newbie on database

> How to count as 1 those duplicate data and those who has duplicate/existing will not count again: this is an example

PARTICIPANT     |   REGISTRATION DATE

```
A           |   2017-04-10
B           |   2017-04-10
B           |   2017-05-11
C           |   2017-07-01
C           |   2017-08-02
D           |   2017-09-01
D           |   2017-09-02
E           |   2020-04-05
E           |   2021-05-20
F           |   2021-05-05
G           |   2021-05-10
H           |   2021-05-25
```

> I want to display something like this ::

REGISTRATION DATE        |   COUNT

```
2017-04           |   2
2017-07           |   1
2017-09           |   1
2020-04           |   1
2021-05           |   3
```

Comment: This is a pretty simple aggregate query.  What have you tried?  Also tag only with the database you are really using.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: (which got closed because of the same conflicting database tags)

Comment: yes sir. That is why my question is closed.

Comment: I am newbie in database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first format date to month only by date_format(column,'%Y-%c')
- group by the month and count(distinct column)

```sql
select date_format(REGISTRATION_DATE,"%Y-%c") as month,count(distinct PARTICIPANT) from tbl group by month
```